# converting \u0040 to @ in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, streamreader, .net

The Facebook graph API's return to me the user's email address as

`foo\u0040bar.com`.

in a JSON object.  I need to convert it to

`foo@bar.com`.

There must be a built in method in .NET that changes the Unicode character expression (\u1234) to the actual unicode symbol.

Do you know what it is?

Note: I prefer not to use JSON.NET or JavaScriptSerializer for performance issues.

I think the problem is in my StreamReader:

```
        requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken;
        request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response2 = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                reader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I tried different encodings for the StreamReader, UTF8, UTF7, Unicode, ... none worked.

Many thanks!

Thanks to L.B for correcting me.  The problem was not in the StreamReader.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong when reading/decoding this. Fixing it after the fact will not be so straightforward.

Comment: Most not trivial - how to extract `\u0040` symbol from the string

Comment: looking back at it it looks like I need to give the StreamReader that reads the JSON the right encoding

Comment: `I prefer not to use JSON.NET or JavaScriptSerializer for performance issues` How many requests do you make to facebook per second? How many CPU cycles do you need more?

Comment: L.B I think and @Henk Holterman also thinks that my StreamReader is at fault. So performance aside, going to other libraries will not solve the problem.

Comment: No, I said 'something'. And that something probably is _not using_ a proper deserializer lib.

Comment: @user277498, Yes it will **solve**, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json responses are not binary data to convert to a string using some encodings. Instead they are strings correctly decoded by your browser or by `HttpWebResponse` as in your example. You need a second procesing on it(regex, deserializers etc) to get the final data.

See what you get with
`webClient.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/HavelVaclav?access_token=????")` without any encoding

```
{"id":"100000042150992",
    "name":"Havel V\u00e1clav",
    "first_name":"Havel",
    "last_name":"V\u00e1clav",
    "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/havel.vaclav",
    "username":"havel.vaclav",
    "gender":"male",
    "locale":"cs_CZ"
}
```

Would your encoding change `\/` to `/`?

So, the problem is not in your `StreamReader`.

Comment: But you accepted  another answer? Where your best solution would be Json.Net, JavaScriptSerializer etc.

Comment: both answers were good. it was a tossup. your answer was what i implemented but @Guffa's answer was the correct answer to my exact question. I want to give you both credit.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is some built in method for that, but that would involve something like using a compiler to parse the string as code...

Use a simple replace:

```
s = s.Replace(@"\u0040", "@");
```

For a more flexible solution, you can use a regular expression that can handle any unicode character:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\\u([\dA-Fa-f]{4})", v => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(v.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString());
```

Comment: The latter is exactly what I was typing. +1

Comment: This is an excellent answer, however looking back I think the fix really should be in my StreamReader. I edited the question to reflect my new thinking.  Many thanks!

Comment: @user277498: I don't know who's version you used, it was edited several times after i posted it. Anyway, I have fixed it now.